# Массовое получение и обновление SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cron

У меня имеется следующая таблица:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `farmers` (
  `id` INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'ID записи',
  `user_id` bigint NOT NULL COMMENT 'ID юзера',
  ...
  `energy` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'Энергия'
  `apples_need` INT(11) UNSIGNED DEFAULT 1 COMMENT 'Сколько нужно яблок в день',
  `apples` INT(11) UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'Яблок нафармлено за день',
  ...

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),

  FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;
```

Теперь, хочу реализовать скрипт, который будет выполняться раз в сутки, в 00:00 через Cron. Суть скрипта следующая и выполнение должно быть разделено на части.

**Первая часть**

1. Получить всех из таблицы `farmers`, у которых `apples` <= `apples_need`;
2. Обнуляем счётчик `apples`.

**Вторая часть**

1. Получить всех из таблицы `farmers`, у которых `apples` > `apples_need`;
2. Посчитать остаток яблок. То есть, если у фермера 10 яблок (`apples = 5`), а ему в сутки нужно добыть 5 (`apples_need` = 5), то вычислить остаток (лишнее кол-во) и конвертировать следующим образом:
   Прибавить лишнее кол-во `apples` к полю `energy`;
3. Обнулить счётчик `apples`.

На словах всё выглядит громоздко, на самом деле, мне кажется, что можно сделать проще. Проблема в том, что не знаю, как правильно построить запросы такого типа, и так, чтобы это создавало как можно меньше загрузки. Поэтому, хотелось бы увидеть пример реализации сих слов. Скрипт будет работать на большое число юзеров.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, так:

```
update farmers
set energy = energy + case when apples > apples_need then apples - apples_need else 0 end,
apples = 0;
```